# why and how do the addresses returned by 'cat /proc/self/maps' change when it's executed again

Tags: linux, proc

I'm trying to understand linux memory management.

Why and how do the addresses returned by 'cat /proc/self/maps' change when it's executed again

> user@notebook:/$ cat /proc/self/maps | grep heap
>
> **55dc94a7c000**-**55dc94a9d000** rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
>
> user@notebook:/$ cat /proc/self/maps | grep heap
>
> **562609879000**-**56260989a000** rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to Address Space Layout Randomization, aka ASLR. Linux will load code and libraries at different locations each time to make it harder to exploit buffer overflows and similar.

You can disable it with

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

which will make the addresses the same each time. You can then re-enable it with:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

and the addresses will be randomized again.

Comment: is it possible that the address ranges change (in size or position) during the runtime of the program (here 'cat')?

Comment: The program can choose to modify its memory space in a number of ways, but ASLR will not automatically change an existing mapping while the program is running.